# Could not download image using php (bad request)

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

iam trying to download image from an url, tried multiple methods (almost every method i found on google) but not yet succeeded, 
Some solutions gives error

```
Found Document has been moved here
```

and most solutions gives error

```
file_get_content: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

One of the solutions i'v tried so far (there are more than 25 i have tried)

```
$fp = fopen ('mydirectory/image.jpg', 'w+');              // open file handle

$ch = curl_init('https://www.otakusmash.com/read-manga/mangas/AIKI/008/Aiki_v02_c08_000.jpg');
            // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // enable if you want
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);          // output to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);      // some large value to allow curl to run for a long time
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);   // Enable this line to see debug prints
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);                              // closing curl handle
fclose($fp);
```

Please help me out

Comment: The code works, if you fix quotes for the file path. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Fixed that, but it only download image of 0 kb from this specific domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a error in your code, Please use below code

```
$fp = fopen ("mydirectory/image.jpg", 'w+');              // open file handle

$ch = curl_init('https://www.otakusmash.com/read-manga/mangas/AIKI/008/Aiki_v02_c08_000.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // enable if you want
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);          // output to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);      // some large value to allow curl to run for a long time
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);   // Enable this line to see debug prints
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);                              // closing curl handle
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks, Awesome. Worked like charm, can you please tell me what was wrong? :)

Comment: this line was comment -- `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: @NomanAli When you try to download any thing from `https` please use that above line.